# Pasted Values deletes Data Validation - Macro Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How are you? I was trying to create an excel´s table to prevent the data entry of wrong numbers.

There´s a column "A" with the next rule:
Column A only allows values between 20 and 40.

The problem is that when i paste values in this column, the data validation does not work. I ve tried with Macros but i´m a newbie and could not resolve the problem.

What I expect is, if I try to paste the next values : (20,30,35,48) in the column "A", get an error message
because 48 is wrong.

Thank u so much!

What I am expecting is described above.